# Dismissing topic request as "Already exists" should allow pointing to a tag

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

Currently when you want to dismiss a topic request with reason "Already exists" you need to link to a topic. If a topic however has its own tag, you should be able to link to that tag instead.

Trying to do that is currently rejected with a message that the link doesn't point to a topic.

Proposal: also allow linking to another tag in the "Already exists" rejection reason.